# How to run a command in child process in grunt tasks?

Tags: gruntjs, child-process

I want to write a grunt task, which will start a server, and run some tests based on that server:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
      sbtRun: {
        options: {
          stdout: true
        },
        command: './sbt run'
      }
   }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

grunt.registerTask('run-test-only', ...);

grunt.registerTask('start-server-and-test', ['shell:sbtRun', 'run-test-only']);
```

But the problem is, the task `./sbt run` is not running in daemon. When I run:

```
grunt start-server-and-test
```

It will blocking in the `shell:sbtRun` task forever.

Is there any way to start it in a child process? So the second task `run-test-only` will be called, and the server will be destroyed automatically after testing?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. I wanted to connect to a database and store the result of a query in a .csv. I created a separate file to do all that work and I was successful in running that file through the command line using:

```
node filename.js
```

I used grunt-shell and grunt-exec to run this command but everytime I saw the same error:

```
const child = require('child_process').exec;
```

Then, I found another grunt plugin i.e grunt-execute which was able to create a child process and the task was completed successfully. You could find more about grunt-execute here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-execute.

Hope this helps.